# BCH Codes example

Tags: abstract-algebra, coding-theory

Suppose we have a binary cyclic code $C$ with length $N=2^d-1$ defined by a primitive root $N^{th}$ root of unity (so generating polynomial is the minimal polynomial for the root).

I want to show two things:

(1) If $g(X)\in\mathbb F_2[X]$, then $g(X)^2=g(X^2)$. I think this is clear because $g(X)\in\mathbb F_2[X]$ but how to write it down in a formal way?

(2) $C$ is a BCH code with design distance $3$, rank $d$ and length $N$.

The BCH code is with design distance $x$ is the cyclic code of length $N$ over $\mathbb F$ defined by the ideal $J=\{P(X)\in\mathbb F[X]: P(\alpha)=P(\alpha ^2)=...=P(\alpha^{x-1})=0\}$ where $1\le x\le N$ and $\alpha$ a primitive root of $X^N-1$ in field $K$

Same problem as in Part (1), it seems clear from the definitin of the BCH code but how to write it down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extended hints:

(1) Any polynomial of $\Bbb{F}_2[X]$ is of the form
$$
g(X)=\sum_{i=0}^n g_iX^i
$$
for some natural number $n$ and coefficients $g_i\in \Bbb{F}_2$. You are expected to just check it out that the identity holds. A shortcut is to observe that $\Bbb{F}_2[X]$ is a commutative ring of characteristic two. In such rings squaring a binomial is easier than usual, because
$$
(a+b)^2=(a+b)(a+b)=a^2+ab+ba+b^2=a^2+2ab+b^2=a^2+b^2.
$$
This result is widely known as *freshman's dream* for some reason (rolls eyes).

(2) Elements of $C$ are multiples of the minimal (=generator) polynomial $f(X)$ of $\alpha$. So you are given that $f(\alpha)=0$. What can you say about $f(\alpha^2)$ in light of part (1)? Your task is basically to check that a polynomial is divisible $f(X)$, if and only if both $\alpha$ and $\alpha^2$ are its zeros.

Comment: Thanks, concerning (2) we know that $f(\alpha^2)=f(\alpha)^2=0$, therefore polynomial divisible $f(X)$.

Comment: Apologies for resurrecting and old post, but there's something that I don't quite understand in your proof. Surely the generating function is of degree $d$; using $(1)$, it is
$$G(X) = (X-\alpha)(X-\alpha^2)...(X-\alpha^{2^{d-1}})$$
as $\alpha^{2d} = \alpha^{N+1} = \alpha$ so we repeat. Then we use the theorem that says that the rank if $N - D = 2^d - d - 1$, where $D = d$ is the degree of the minimum polynomial?